# kotlin "contains" doesn't work as expected

Tags: arrays, kotlin, compare, contains

I am working with a method which filters the preferences which match with the ids, I am using the `contains` method, but even though the values are the same, the `contains` is showing a `false` in each iteration. The method looks like:

```
private fun filterPreferencesByIds(context: MyPodCastPresenterContext): List<FanPreferences> {
            return context.preferences?.filter {
                context.ids.contains(it.id)
            }
        }
```

The values of the arrays are:

for the `context.ids`:
"B52594F5-80A4-4B18-B5E2-8F7B12E92958" and "3998EDE7-F84B-4F02-8E15-65F535080100"

[image]

And for the `context.preferences`:

[image]

But even though, when the first and the final ids have the same id value as the `context.ids`, the contains is false in the debug. I think it could be related with the types in the `context.ids` rows `Json$JsonTextNode`. Because when I did the same with numeric values hardcoded the compare is successful.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is JsonTextNode defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the type of `FanPreferences.id` is `String` and the type of `context.ids` list element is `JsonTextNode`, you won't find an element equal to the given id string, because it's not of String type.

Try mapping your context ids to the list of strings before filtering:

```
val ids = context.ids.map { it.toString() }.toSet()
return context.preferences?.filter {
    ids.contains(it.id)
}
```

Note that calling `toString()` on `JsonTextNode` might be not the best way to get the string data from it. It's better to consult the API documentation of that class to find it out.